# MDM iOS 9 app install failure

Tags: ios, ipad, ipa, mdm, airwatch

**Why will the IPA SideLoad, but not install via AirWatch?**

Our in house application will install when side-loaded from a Mac using iTunes.

However, for enterprise wide distribution, we use AirWatch. When using the exact same IPA, via AirWatch, the app fails to install, returning an error that reads "*Unable to Install*" without any other information. So what am I missing?

If the provision profiles and signing are not correct, I shouldn't be able to build the app in the first place. Correct?

And once built, and side-loadable, it stand to reason that it should install via AirWatch without issue.

When exploring the IPA from Apple Configurator, we have retrieved the following from the log file:

> Oct 23 14:19:23 Grant-Test-iPad ondemandd[171] : Unable to update manifest, we cannot find its bundle URL.
> Oct 23 14:19:23 Grant-Test-iPad ondemandd[171] : Calling applicationDownloadInitiated: reply block with error : Error Domain=_OnDemandResourcesErrorDomain Code=114 "(null)" UserInfo={NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=LSApplicationProxy returned no bundle URL.}
> Oct 23 14:19:23 Grant-Test-iPad itunesstored[130] : [ApplicationWorkspace]: Installing software package with bundleID: com.healthsouth.HSPreassessment: bundleVersion: 1.1.10023 path: /var/mobile/Media/Downloads/1966681134488032800/-3221430272025313765
> Oct 23 14:19:23 Grant-Test-iPad itunesstored[130] : File starts with 0x0d0a0d0a; expected 0x504b0304
> Oct 23 14:19:23 Grant-Test-iPad itunesstored[130] : BundleValidator: Invalid archive for bundlerIdenfier: com.healthsouth.HSPreassessment path: /var/mobile/Media/Downloads/1966681134488032800/-3221430272025313765
> Oct 23 14:19:23 Grant-Test-iPad itunesstored[130] : [ApplicationWorkspace]: Bundle validated for bundleIdentifier: com.healthsouth.HSPreassessment success: 0
> Oct 23 14:19:23 Grant-Test-iPad itunesstored[130] : [ApplicationWorkspace]: Uninstalling application placeholder for bundleIdentifier: com.healthsouth.HSPreassessment; success: 0
> Oct 23 14:19:23 Grant-Test-iPad itunesstored[130] : [ApplicationWorkspace]: Failed to install application: com.healthsouth.HSPreassessment; /var/mobile/Media/Downloads/1966681134488032800/-3221430272025313765; (null)
> Oct 23 14:19:31 Grant-Test-iPad corecaptured[425] : CCProfileMonitor::freeResources done
> Oct 23 14:19:31 Grant-Test-iPad corecaptured[425] : Got an XPC error: Connection invalid
> Oct 23 14:19:31 Grant-Test-iPad corecaptured[425] : CCLogTap::profileRemoved, Owner: com.apple.driver.AppleBCMWLANCore0, Name: DriverLogs

Obviously the device being used is named Grant-Test-iPad.

The question to me seems to be that if, as the first line suggest, the manifest cannot be updated, how are we able to side-load the app?

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: You could install an IPA (built for AdHoc distribution) using iTunes, but you won't be able to run it if the device isn't included in the list.
The error could be referring to the manifest file included in IPAs built for Ad-Hoc distribution.

To build an App in XCode you need a valid AppID and development and distribution certificates and provisioning profiles.
To distribute the IPAs with AirWatch (or via website) you'll need an IPA signed for enterprise distribution, and the user will need to grant trust to the development team